# How to get previous month and expected format from month picker using moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using jquery.ui.monthpicker library. For month picker I am getting date like `07/2017`. From this date string I need to calculate previous month and formatted like `1707` using [moment js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code may solve your problem.

```
moment("07/2017", "MM/YYYY").subtract(1, 'months').format('YYMM');
```

Answer (score 1):

DEMO at https://jsfiddle.net/nffswx75/

```
    var dt = "07/2017";

    alert(moment(dt,"MM/YYYYY").format('YYMM'));

    alert(moment(dt,"MM/YYYYY").add(-1, 'months').format('YYMM'));

alert(moment(dt,"MM/YYYYY").subtract(1, 'months').format('YYMM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let moment create a `date` object from a string by telling it what format your date is in.

```
let dateString: string = "07/2017";
var date = moment(dateString, "MM/YYYY").subtract(1, 'month').format("YYMM");
```